# How to randomly select values from a given column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So if I have a column that has unique values:

```
A
100
110
231
194
572
200
```

And I wanted to randomly select a fixed amount of values from it (ie. 3).

Is there like a code to do that? For example `=random(a:a, 3)`

Comment: Do you want to avoid picking the same item more than once??

Comment: Preferably, but I don't really mind it. That column initially wouldn't have duplicate values to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$6,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT(A$1:A$6)))
```

and copy down two cells.  Since each pick is completely independent, duplicates may occur:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To help insure that the same item is **not** picked more than one, in **B1** through **B6** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and use this formula instead:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$6,MATCH(LARGE($B$1:$B$6,ROW()),$B$1:$B$6,0))
```

[image]